# Arduino Ethernet shield not connecting to a website

Tags: connection, arduino, ethernet

I am trying to send data to a local server using the code below:
The server does not receive the data through the Ethernet shield. It says it connects successfully.
I have pinged Google with the Ethernet shield and also sent data through the browser using the link in char server[]. Both cases work well. Does anyone know the problem?

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 0, 116 };
char server[] = "http://192.168.0.175/test-app/listener?data=1234"; 

EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
 Serial.begin(9600);

delay(1000);

Serial.println("connecting...");

if (client.connect(server,8080)) {
 Serial.println("connected");
 //client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
 //client.println();
 client.stop();
} else {
 Serial.println("connection failed");
}
 } 

void loop()
{
  if (client.connect(server,80)){
  client.stop();
  Serial.println("yay!!");
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using port 8080 in setup() but port 80 in loop()?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving full path in the server name, it only needs to be the base URL.